# What are the height (and weight) size ranges for each size category of creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, changeling, size-scaling

Changelings have the ability to change their height and weight, but not so much they change a size category:

> [...] You can also adjust your height and weight, but not so much that your size changes. [...]

While they start out as a Medium creature, there is scope for them to be affected by something like Enlarge/Reduce, which would then enable them to change their height (and weight) to any size within that size category.

As a result, I'm looking for height (and weight) ranges for each size category in the game. (I've not been able to find such a chart)

If there isn't a size chart in 5e, answers from other editions are welcome.

Comment: It's worthwhile to point out, I am a DM and looking at this from a DMs perspective, so I can come up with a reasonable set of metrics to work with, but that isn't especially relevant to the question (the fact I'm a DM), as the idea behind the question is to get a set of ranges that enable both sets of people at the table, to make informed decisions on choices and rulings, given the specific mechanics of this race. Outliers, while potentially useful for "rule-bending", are just that, outliers, but the most useful information is actually the range where two categories overlap...

Comment: ...as it gives an idea that the true answer is actually somewhere in that overlap range, or at the less extreme edges of it on either side (eg larger end of a potential Small/Medium overlap for the lower limit on Medium creatures and the lower end of that limit for the upper size range of Small creatures)

Comment: Are you interested in applications most useful for changelings (i.e. humanoid forms), or heights and weights more broadly? There is data for the former if you're interested, but only for Medium and Small creatures.

Comment: @BBeast I'm interested in heights and weights more broadly, as the changeling restriction limits their changes in height and weight to size category limits. So while they are limited to humanoid forms, they are not limited to staying within the normal height bounds for those forms (so they could make themselves be an abnormally large dwarf, for example, that towers over all humans).

Comment: Scaling weight is easy if you have height scaling and a base weight. Doubling height translates to a roughly eight-fold increase in weight assuming all dimensions increase proportionately (they probably do) and density is preserved (it probably is).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That might be a way to construct such a table, the problem is coming up with the base to start from (and also making some specific density assumptions....which don't really hold for both very small creatures, like birds which can have hollow bones, or very large creatures, like Whales, who live in a much more buoyant environment), but that would certainly be an interesting approach to an answer

Comment: My point was more that if you have a table for height scaling, and you have an existing creature to scale, you can compute weight scaling based on that. IOW, you don’t really need a table for weight, just for height (because it’s reasonable to assume in most cases that a given creature’s density won’t change as it gets bigger or smaller).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn The problem here is that the Changeling specifically can change their weight to be *any* weight within the size category, so they could in theory make themselves a super-dense or super-light version of a particular form, without changing the shape of that form (which is why I'm looking for the ranges)

Comment: Is the [tag:changeling] tag useful here? The answers won't be different without it because of how you've written the question.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Yes, because the question is prompted by a specific racial feature, and will be useful to other people looking for information to help them rule on the use of that specific racial feature. Without the tag, it's much less visible for players and DMs playing with that specific race

Comment: @illustro anybody searching '[tag:changeling][tag:creature-size]' (i.e. your example situation) would still find this with only one of those tags. But people interested changelings has to scroll past this if they are only looking for [tag:changeling] questions

Comment: @AncientSwordRage While the headline title doesn't mention changeling the body of the question does and sets out why I'm looking this information. The question is specifically related to changelings. You could certainly format a duplicate of this question that *doesn't* ask about changelings, and thus wouldn't have the tag, but this one does and I think should have it.

Comment: Related: [What does a creature's size refer to?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198702/what-does-a-creature-s-size-refer-to)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While there doesn't appear to be a simple table in Dungeons & Dragons 5th Edition [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), there was one in the Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) [*Dungeon Master's Guide* 2003, 29](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementPositionAndDistance.htm#tableCreatureSizeAndScale). Though it's not as necessary in 5e to have a 'rule for everything', size in 5e is almost exclusively defined by the space a creature takes up in combat. The rest of the dimensions, height, length, width, weight, et al. are left somewhat nebulous. For the changeling, one might start with the height and weight ranges for other medium humanoids, as far as those numbers exist as statistics, for example.

It may be helpful to use the table from the 3.5 DMG as a basis to start your descriptions and rulings from. Truncated below:

| Size Category | Maximum Height | Max. Weight | Space |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Fine** | 6in. or less | 1/8 Lb or less | 1/2 ft. |
| **Diminutive** | 1 ft. | 1 Lb | 1 ft. |
| **Tiny** | 2 ft. | 8 Lb | 2 1/2 ft. |
| **Small** | 4 ft. | 60 Lb | 5 ft. |
| **Medium** | 8 ft. | 500 Lb | 5 ft. |
| **Large** | 16 ft. | 4000 Lb | 10 ft. |
| **Huge** | 32 ft | 32000 Lb | 15 ft. |
| **Gargantuan** | 64 ft. | 250000 Lb | 20 ft. |
| **Colossal** | 64 ft. or more | 250000 Lb or more | 30 ft. |

Height is also length for 'long' rather than 'tall' creatures.

Weight is for creatures made of flesh.

Space is usually what is listed, but exceptions exist.

The linked SRD page (correctly) extrapolates the changes as minimums as well as maximums.

---

I view this as a good starting point for description and hammering my monsters to fit the scales of D&D.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for that doesn't (currently) exist in 5e. I've been able to replicate the height portion of this using the little information 5e has on Height and size linking, and it matches these 3.5e ranges (weight is much fuzzier). As such I'm happy to use the 3.5e table and ranges.

Comment: 5e mostly moved away from this style of table, and it seems intentional - so while this might work well for the querent, it is unfortunate that the answer doesn't go into more detail about what 5e has to offer in this regard.

Comment: Would you prefer something along the lines of "Though it's not as necessary in 5e to have a 'rule for everything', size in 5e is almost exclusively defined by the space a creature takes up in combat. The rest of the dimensions, height, length, width, weight, et al. are left to the DM to flesh out, at his preference. The table from the 3.5 DMG can be used as a basis to start your descriptions and rulings from, if it helps you." @Akixkisu?

Comment: @Chemus Yes, something like that — when does exact size matter? Mostly in encounter situations - and then we are talking about controlled space which the changeling can't change - and in all other situations from a mechanics point only space matters; and when size matters e. g. for an intimidation check - it is only important that the shape is looming dangerous, tall and heavy/agile all of which are narrative features and none of which rely on exact measurements.

Comment: @Akixkisu Some of that is simply play, or narrative, style. Having a reasonable starting point for being able to gauge whether a description fits within a particular size category can be a useful tool for those who want it.

Comment: @Akixkisu size can matter in out of combat situations too. "You are faced with a 20ft high wall and guards who won't let you in. How do you proceed?" One way would be "I cast Enlarge on X (who happens to be a changeling)" and X saying, "I make myself 30 feet tall and lift everyone over the wall". But you can't figure out if that is doable without the upper size of the Large size category. 30 feet might be totally fine or completely not allowed.

Comment: @illustro That seems like a non-issue to me. It is not the exact 32ft. that matters - it is can I cast enlarge and then adjust my size as a changeling to get over that wall (that my math eyes precisely measure at 20ft.)? And in that situation, the only problem stems from providing exact measurements in the first place.

Comment: @Akixkisu The communication of feet measurements would be for the ease of understanding of people at the table. The fiction of the game could have the Changeling knowing roughly whether or not their largest size would reach the top of the wall or not (without necessarily knowing how big that is). Also it's a legitimate way that people can play the game.

Comment: @illustro It is a legitimate approach - that is why I asked this valid answer to include that section to improve it. It solved your issue, and now it should help even more people who look at it. When you communicate that way, in ft,/grid squares, it introduces a lot of meta-information that facilitates some playstyles and stifles others.

Answer (score 18):

No official guidance is given in the rules, however rather than looking at exact height/weight ranges, you can instead look at this list I made and ask yourself if the player is closer in size to a sheep than a human, or weighs more like a horse than a normal person.

| Size Category | Example Creatures |
| --- | --- |
| **Tiny** | Badger, Bat, **Cat**, Crab, Fox, Frog, Hare, Hawk, Lizard, Owl, Snake, Honeybee, Quipper, Rat, Raven, Scorpion, Sea Horse, Spider, Weasel |
| **Small** | Baboon, Eagle, Jackal, Octopus, **Sheep** |
| **Medium** | Ape, Black Bear, Boar, Deer, Dolphin, Goat, **Human**, Hyena, Mastiff, Mule, Panther, Pig, Pony, Reef Shark, Seal, Vulture, Wolf |
| **Large** | Brown Bear, Camel, Cow, Crocodile, Elk, **Horse**, Lion, Ox, Polar Bear, Rhinoceros, Tiger, Walrus |
| **Huge** | **Elephant**, Killer Whale |
| **Gargantuan** | **Sperm Whale** |

I have bolded one in each category which I think gives a representative idea of how big/heavy each category is.

Comment: Sheep typically have a weight of 50–100 kg (100–200 lbs), pretty much the same as humans.

Answer (score 10):

### Height is never really defined

There's a reason you don't remember such a chart, because 5e doesn't have one. It doesn't really spend a lot of time on height outside of cylindrical spell effects and player characters. The same goes for verticallity in general, really.

The only part the game really defines (PHB 191) is the creature sizes dictating the space the occupy in combat, which doesn't cover verticaly, and  is "not an expression of its physical dimensions."

There is a chart on page 248 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* which shows creatures of different height, but it doesn't give you what you were looking for without a *lot* of extrapolation:

[image: Illustration depicting height from the DMG]

It rather obviously doesn't cover anything non-bipedal (the worm isn't much help because that shape doesn't generalize well, and Gargantuan is just anything bigger than Huge anyway), nor does it actually say anything about what the limits or borders are. You could maybe take the depicted heights as (approximate) upper bounds, it gives little for lower bounds if you want to cover all existing monsters. (The extreme end would be [rug of smothering](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/rug-of-smothering) which is Large and well... one carpet tall).

Comment: Thank you, I'd forgotten about that chart!

Answer (score 4):

### About Space Controlled

What we get [from official sources](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Size) about size is about the area you have control over:

| Size | Space | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tiny | 2 1/2 by 2 1/2 ft. | Imp, sprite |
| Small | 5 by 5 ft. | Giant rat, goblin |
| Medium | 5 by 5 ft. | Orc, werewolf |
| Large | 10 by 10 ft. | Hippogriff, ogre |
| Huge | 15 by 15 ft. | Fire giant, treant |
| Gargantuan | 20 by 20 ft. or larger | Kraken, purple worm |

Which I believe is fuzzy by design. I think it is along the lines of designers thinking, "We all know what medium creature looks like, and what a huge creature looks like, but we don't want to some hard fast rule that 9' is medium and 9'1" is large."

### Height

In general, I think a height less then next control space is about what you'll in the most monster stat blocks for  a given size, as a general rule of thumb. That is, I wouldn't let a medium humanoid creature get taller than 10ft., because with a sword their reach would logically be larger than the 5 foot space.  Small and medium, as currently written, is a weird distinction. So maybe something like:

- Tiny, anything less that 1 feet tall.
- Small 1 to 3 ft tall.
- Medium 3' to 10' ft tall. ([average adult humans have a height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_modern_human) of 5.6)
- Large 10' to 15' ft tall.
- Huge 15' to 20' ft tall.
- Gargantuan 20' or more.

Keeping in mind, again, that these are just numbers I picked out of the air, based on what kind of makes sense given the control area described above. Most of the time, just setting the max to control size of the next size. Although it does fit with [the diagram in the DMG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/dungeon-masters-guide#Size).

### Weight

Weight is more difficult and more fuzzy, because a lot of monsters and such are made out of weird materials of different density than human flesh and bone.  Perhaps the best bet it to look at the weights of the real life creatures in each category when possible.  Here's some for reference:

- Tiny: [Bats weigh](https://a-z-animals.com/animals/bat/) at up to 3.3 lbs.
- Small: [Rats weigh](https://www.arc.wa.gov.au/?page_id=125) about 1 lbs., larger house cats weigh about 10 lbs.
- Medium: An [average adult humans weigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_weight) on average 130 to 160 lbs. depending on country
- Large: An [average horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse) weighs 660 lbs.
- Huge: [African Elephants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_bush_elephant) weigh 6 metric tons or 13,000 lbs on average.
- Gargantuan: [Sperm Whales weigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_whale) 31,000 to 90,000 lbs.

I'd be tempted to generalize that out to be something like:

- Tiny < 10 lbs.
- Small: <100 lbs.
- Medium: < 400 lbs.
- Large: < 1,000 lbs.
- Huge: < 25,000 lbs.
- Gargantuan: > 25,000 lbs.

Comment: Good job finding some real-world reference weights. If you made medium < 500 lbs, the weight chart would be even simpler with factor 5 and 10 steps, and it would cap off with Floating Disc, too.

Answer (score 3):

### 5e only offers height ranges for two categories, but from that, we can extrapolate the remaining ranges

After some (detailed) digging, I found that the *Players Handbook* lists two sets of measurements for the size categories that Player Characters fit into:

> Characters of most races are Medium, a size category including creatures that are roughly 4 to 8 feet tall. Members of a few races are Small (between 2 and 4 feet tall), which means that certain rules of the game affect them differently. [...]

*PHB > Chapter 2: Races > Racial Traits > Size*

Helpfully, the wording of this tells us describes the general *size category* ranges, as opposed to just the size category as it applies to Player Characters. So this gives us a starting point for our Height calculation.

We can then use the text of the Enlarge/Reduce spell:

> **Enlarge.** The target's size doubles in all dimensions, and its weight is multiplied by eight. This growth increases its size by one category - from Medium to Large, for example.
>
> **Reduce.** The target's size is halved in all dimensions, and its weight is reduced to one-eighth of normal. This reduction decreases its size by one category - from Medium to Small, for example.

So if we double our upper and lower bounds we should get the Height ranges for size categories above Medium, and if we halve our upper and lower bounds we should get the height ranges for categories below Small.

First we should sanity check this method, using our two known size categories, and thankfully it works as expected with those upper and lower bounds!

Extrapolating this, and using the size categories we have defined in the rules for 5e (Tiny, Small, Medium, Large, Huge, and Gargantuan) we get the following table:

| Size Category | Minimum Height | Maximum Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Tiny** | 1 ft. | 2ft. |
| **Small** | 2 ft. | 4ft. |
| **Medium** | 4 ft. | 8ft. |
| **Large** | 8 ft. | 16ft. |
| **Huge** | 16 ft | 32ft. |
| **Gargantuan** | 32 ft. | 64ft. |

Technically, given the fact Tiny and Gargantuan are the minimum and maximum size categories respectively, their respective lower and upper bounds wouldn't have limits on them as shown in the above table. I found it useful, however, to include them, as this method would also enable us to generate additional size categories above and below the default given ones in the 5e rules.

Weight, is trickier, as the canonical Height and Weight tables, showing in the PHB, Volo's Guide to Monsters, and Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica (as well as other 1-2 new race specific source books), list out weights of playable races. We can use these as guideposts, but the ranges are a lot fuzzier and require a lot more work. I'll update this answer when I've collated that information.

Comment: +1, might also be good to point out that these apply only to the humanoid body plan (which is  OK, it's the only relevant one for changeling). For example, you can have huge snakes like the Giant Constrictor Snake, that would have a hard time to get to more than three of four feet of height slithering along.

Comment: These sizes are also supported by examples in the monster manual, which has the smallest Huge giant, the Hill Giant, at 16 feet, and the archetypical large humanoid, the Ogre, at 9-10 feet.

Answer (score -2):

I had to delve into this topic today because of an encounter I'm preparing for the weekend, and I went down a rabbit hole so I thought to share.

I used the 3.5 table, enlarge/reduce description, and material weights by cubic feet to arrive at this:

Tiny: 1-2ft, 1-8lb
Small: 2-4ft, 8-64lb
Medium: 4-8ft, 64-512lb
Large: 8-16ft, 512-4096lb
Huge: 16-32ft, 4096-32768lb
Gargantuan: 32ft<, 32768lb<

You can start from less than 1lb, but the values hold up pretty well as is. If you want to calculate weight by material, you can use water/oil/fat/leather as base (60lb per cubic feet) and then multiply the value according to the difference, for example: Dry Wood is 30lb which means it weights half as much, while iron weights 8.33 times the value.

That's how I did it at least, you can change it to fit your taste.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. Could you walk us through how you derived those numbers?