# Does the Rune Knight fighter's Giant’s Might feature affect the character's height?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, creature-size, rune-knight

The [Rune Knight fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#RuneKnight) gets the [Giant's Might](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#Giant%E2%80%99sMight-2992763) feature at 3rd level (TCoE, p. 45), which grants several benefits for 1 minute. One of these benefits causes you to become Large-sized.

Does the Giant's Might feature actually alter your height, the way the [*Enlarge/Reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) spell does?

Comment: Are you suggesting it might just make you expand horizontally?

Comment: No I’m asking what affect becoming large actually had on height. As we know increasing or decreasing height doesn’t affect what size a creature is, so I was wondering if increasing a creatures size affects a creatures height

Comment: Related: [What are the height (and weight) size ranges for each size category of creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195388/what-are-the-height-and-weight-size-ranges-for-each-size-category-of-creature)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no specific height or weight specified, but you definitely get bigger. The size change language includes:

> If you lack the room to become Large, your size doesn't change.

Even if common English definitions of relative sizes didn't apply, this would still imply that you in fact get physically larger (if you didn't, you wouldn't need the extra space). Aside from that it's up to the DM; if I were in charge, I'd just make you the size of some common humanoid Large creature (e.g. an ogre), but there's no fixed size specified, so anything reasonable works.

Comment: While there is no fixed size specified, there's a table that shows how much space creature controls here: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters and ot might be a good guideline of how relative size should change. Here, I would extrapolate that warrior roughly doubles in height.

Comment: @Mołot: Sure. Possibly more than doubles (since it will expand Small characters directly to Large as well, and Small characters are typically between 1/3 and 2/3rds the height of a Medium character). They were far less precise on sizes, so anything vaguely in the right size range is reasonable.

Comment: But large just refers to how much space a creature controls, and saying you don’t have enough space to become large could just mean that if their isn’t enough space for you to control a 10ft by 10ft area than you don’t gain the increased area control

Comment: Large increases the space the creature occupies *because the creature is bigger*. No, it doesn't mean you're 10'x10' in horizontal area, anymore than a Medium creature is 5'x5'. But you have to occupy a meaningful percentage of the space to control it, and if you *didn't* occupy a meaningful percentage of the space, there'd be no need for the squeezing rules tied directly to your size; you not only *can* control that much space, it also describes how much space you *need* to function at full efficiency in combat, and if you weren't getting bigger, there's no reason you'd *need* more space.

Comment: Yes, game mechanics-wise, they left everything but the space occupied unspecified. No, that doesn't mean you can "become Large" without changing size (barring a rule that says otherwise explicitly). They may not have explicitly said "this is precise dimensions that constitute Large", but at least among the humanoids with provided heights, [they all fall between about 8' and 15' tall](https://roleplayersrespite.com/dnd-sizes-explained) (vs. Medium at 4'-8'). The DM could reasonably say that you grow to any height in that range; for non-humanoids, perhaps shorter but broader. But you do grow.

Comment: @Cellheim: And I'll note, your quote from the comment "As we know increasing or decreasing height doesn’t affect what size a creature is" may be all you can get from the specified rules (to prevent a rules lawyer playing an 8' Goliath from getting themselves stretched on a rack to 8'1" and claiming they should be Large now), but personally, if I had a player who doubled (or more) in height (and proportionately in other dimensions), I'd bump their size category, because the alternative is ridiculous on its face. D&D isn't a physics simulator, but it tries to vaguely relate to the real world.